# Way to detect addresses on websites / Which regex?

Tags: regex, street-address

Who has a good concept to automatically detect adresses on websites with a parser?

I though about something simple like:
"contains letters, numbers and has between 3 and 15 words".

Unfortunately adresses are different in UK, US, Germany, Spain a.s.o.
Who could help me with code snippets, regexps, ideas?

thank you!

Comment: What language are you using?  And what are you trying to do?  Some more info on what you will do with the addresses might help with the solution?

Comment: There are too many formats, and too much random stuff could be interpreted as an address. But if you have some format specifications for possible addresses, that could help.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but we may have solved it, at least for US addresses.  We wrote an [address extractor](http://smartystreets.com/products/liveaddress-api/extract) to do just that.  It's not a simple problem and it doesn't work with just REGEX.  We are utilizing REGEX to look for particular types of strings but also limiting it as much as possible to get the best candidate strings.  Once we pull those out of the input, they are checked against our address validation engine.  REGEX+validation gives a very good result. Without the validation, it's just a good guess but you can't know when you are right and when you are wrong.